# Is Azure Application Insights a time-series database?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I was reading some on the Prometheus time-series database, on what their core [model](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/) was. I've never understood what exactly a [time-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) database was until then. Excited enough, I started wondering about Azure Application Insights. Sure enough, Application Insights is a very powerful tool and easy to use for .NET Core devs, especially ASP.NET Core. I've used it for years and like it a lot.

I haven't found any [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) (nor un-official) that states whether Application Insights is a time-series database. From looking at the portal, it's atleast presented as a "normal" relational storage.

This brings us to my question - anyone know what kind of database Application Insights actually is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was working at Microsoft when AppInsights was launched and the team that worked on it was in the same building as me and we often dogfooded their stuff - things might have changed since then, but if I remember correctly it was using a then-internal and proprietary quasi-relational store that was productized as Azure Data Lake - with plenty of indexing of temporal data, but I don't believe at the time it was a true time-series database.

Comment: Application Insights includes many products. Are you talking about Logs or Metrics exploration?

Comment: @ZakiMa I'm (obviously not) an expert in this field - but even if Application Insights has mutliple products on top of it, that doesnt matter for this particular question, right? I mean, if it's a time-series or not has more to do with the underlying database rather than GUI's (Logs or Metrics explorer) on top? If i'm wrong, then yes i'm talking about Logs

Answer (score 1):

I think the reality is more complicated (disclaimer: I'm a part of Azure Monitor team) =) There are many underlying databases to power various experiences. Metrics and Logs are powered by different solutions. Recently we released Azure Data Explorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/). Essentially this is a backend which powers both Application Insights and Log Analytics.

Re: time-series. Azure Data Explorer stores all ingested data. Timestamp is one of columns.